# Node js mosca broker error: Expected `schema` to be an object or boolean

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosca

I have created a simple broker:

```
var mosca = require("mosca");
var settings = {
  port: 1883,
};

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);

server.on("ready", function () {
  console.log("ready");
});
```

I get this error when i run i run the file:

```
/home//Documents/mqtt/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:107
    throw new SchemaError('Expected `schema` to be an object or boolean');
    ^
SchemaError: Expected `schema` to be an object or boolean
    at Validator.validate (/home//Documents/mqtt/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:107:11)
    at Object.validate (/home//Documents/mqtt/node_modules/mosca/lib/options.js:264:26)
    at new Server (/home//Documents/mqtt/node_modules/mosca/lib/server.js:104:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home//Documents/mqtt/broker.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  schema: undefined
}
```

I am running:

node: v12.18.4

npm: 6.14.6

Comment: Don't you have to define your data store??  https://github.com/moscajs/mosca
For that matter, you should be running Aedes rather than Mosca:  https://github.com/moscajs/aedes

Answer (score 7):

Like JD Allen said, better to run aedes than mosca, it's broken after it's dependency jsonschema updated to version 1.2.8, you can manually install jsonschema 1.2.6 to run it without error. it's not yet broken before updated to 1.2.8

Answer (score 5):

comment this line in `validator.js` (`\node_modules\jsonschema\lib\validator.js:111`):

```js
if((typeof schema !== 'boolean' && typeof schema !== 'object') || schema === null){
     throw new SchemaError('Expected `schema` to be an object or boolean');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the runtime go to \node_modules\jsonschema\lib\validator.js. Replace the code on line 106 with

```js
if((typeof schema == 'boolean' && typeof schema == 'object') || schema === null){
```

Comment: can a variable be `boolean` and `object` at the same time?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Editing dependencies is not a good solution, the right answer if to use aedes